# Matrix inversion trick.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A:R^d\to R^n$ be a  linear map. My lecturer mentioned that by some simple fiddling, one can compute the inverse, $(A\circ A^T)^{-1}$ as a simple function of the inverse $(A^T\circ A)^{-1}$ (which may be computationally useful say if $d << n$ for example). I haven't been able to figure how to do this, though. I am aware of the fact that $(CD)^{-1}= D^{-1}C^{-1}$, but this doesn't help much as $A$ won't necessarily be a square matrix! Hints/ideas much appreciated.

Comment: If $n < d$, $A^T A$ can't be invertible, because it has rank at most $n$.  
Similarly, if $n > d$, $A A^T$ can't be invertible.
Perhaps you mean a pseudo-inverse?

Comment: Does the $\circ$ denote the usual matrix product?

Comment: Robert's point about dependency on rank is well made.
Denoting the pseudo-inverse of 
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$
by $A^{+}$ a couple of possibly relevant facts about the pseudo-inverse, and which relate to $(A A^{T})^{-1}$ and $(A^{T} A)^{-1}$ are:
If $\textrm{rank}(A) = n$ then $A^{+} = A^{T}( A A^{T})^{-1}$ and $A A^{+} = I_{n}$.
If $\textrm{rank}(A) = d$ then $A^{+} = (  A^{T} A)^{-1} A^{T}$ and $ A^{+} A= I_{d}$.